# Can tags be visible on answers when searching for posts?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When I search on Stack Overflow, I get questions and answers. Unfortunately, I can only see the tags associated to questions. When an answer has been matched, [I get no tags.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=expression%20tree)

[image: tags or no tags]

I think it makes sense to see the tags associated with the question to which the answer was given.

Moreover, we are able to see the title of the questions, and not the tags, whereas title and tags are extremely coupled (we doesn't allow the name of the langage in the title, because we want it in the tags).

Comment: That would be too confusing in my opinion. Answer has no tags. Why you want to see the tags of parent questions?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : How can I analyse if an answer is relevant to what I am searching if I can only see the title? Moreover, wee see the title of the questions, and not the tags, whereas title and tags are extremely coupled.

Comment: If you want only specific tags you can add them to the search query, e.g. [`expression tree [algorithm] or [express]`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=expression+tree+%5Balgorithm%5D+or+%5Bexpress%5D)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You'd want to see tags on answers for the same reason you'd want to see tags on questions IMO.

Comment: @Dukeling well, guess I'm in a minority here. :)